# How to get the first column of the list?

Tags: python, list

I want to extract the data for the first column. I want the output only have `[male, farmer]` and the rest are ignored. What should I do?

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats

data = np.array([[11, "male",1222,"teacher"],[23,"female",333,"student"],[15,"male",542,"security"],[44,"male",4422,"farmer"],[25,"female",553,"farmer"]])

# type of the data above
types = ["num","cat","num","cat"]
idx = []
for index, _type in enumerate(types):
    if _type == 'cat':
        idx.append(index)

mode = []
for i in idx:
    mode.append(stats.mode(data[:,i]))
print("mode: {}".format(mode))
```

If the code `[sub[0] for sub in mode]` is included in the code, the output is still messy although only have the first column (the output is shown below).

`mode: [array(['male'], dtype='<U11'), array(['farmer'], dtype='<U11')]`

Comment: What is mode and ModeResult here? How to generate this data?

Comment: I have added my code with another example which illustrate the same question, please help me, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## UPDATE

Try:

```
[element[0][0] for element in mode]
```

Generally, [x for x in iterable_structure] will allow you to access each element in the list, process it and create new list. Take a look at:

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

Comment: I unable to obtain a clean column 1 data from the list based on the solution given, I have edited my post, any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Perhaps try [sub[0][0] for sub in l] then. With one extra [0] you should get the result you want.

Comment: thanks for the help, that is excatly what i want! :)

Answer (score 2):

Does that help?

```
In [1]: l=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
In [2]: [sub[0] for sub in l]
Out[2]: [1, 4, 7]
```

Comment: `[array(['management'], dtype='<U13'), array(['married'], dtype='<U13'), array(['secondary'], dtype='<U13'), array(['no'], dtype='<U13'), array(['no'], dtype='<U13'), array(['no'], dtype='<U13'), array(['cellular'], dtype='<U13'), array(['may'], dtype='<U13'), array(['unknown'], dtype='<U13')]`

Comment: This is what I obtained, seems like still messy, anyway to only extract the `management, married,....` ?

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.array([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]])

>>> x
array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
    [5, 6, 7, 8]])

>>> x[:,0] # for returning the first column using '0'
array([1, 5])
```

I think this might help you